# Import javax API in test automation project using Maven module and Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

I am working on test automation using IntelliJ + Maven module. At the moment I want to implement a class to check email with selenium webdriver. When I import these in my project:

```
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
```

then compiler says : Cannot resolve symbol ...

I guess I am missing some settings with the Maven project. Do I have to add any special tag in pom.xml so I can import java API? Thanks

My POM file is below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>jsproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <selenium.version>2.48.2</selenium.version>
        <overwrite.binaries>false</overwrite.binaries>
        <browser>firefox</browser>
        <threads>1</threads>
        <remote>false</remote>
        <seleniumGridURL/>
        <platform/>
        <browserVersion/>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <!--<testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>-->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <index>true</index>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <mode>development</mode>
                                <url>${project.url}</url>
                                <key>value</key>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>                
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>                
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Check the presence of javamail jar in your buildpath/maven repository?

Comment: @darrengorman: I updated my POM file. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the javamail dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And with the version of your choice instead of `1.5.2`

UPDATE:

This dependency contains both javamail api and 
com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory , which is another library built on top of javamail, I guess.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

so just replace the current with the above one and it should work.

Comment: Great! Thanks you, this is what I was missing in my POM. Another package: import com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory , do you know which dependency for it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Thats another jar built on top of javamail , see the update